# How to order dynamic buttons in FieldReflector

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using FieldReflector to add dynamic buttons in MS Bot framework.
I would like the "I want a new account" to appear as the last button, but for some reason it always appears first.
Any idea how to do that?

I have tried adding that field in the beginning and at the end but nothing worked.

```
public static IForm<BoardForm> BuildForm()
    {
        var customFormBuilder = CreateCustomFormBuilder<BoardForm>();
        return customFormBuilder
            .Field(nameof(CloudType))
            .Field(nameof(ExistingCluster), active: IsPublicCloudChosen)
            .Field(nameof(ExistingClusterName), active: IsExistingClusterChosen)
            .Field(new FieldReflector<BoardForm>(nameof(ExistingAccountName))
                .SetType(null)
                .SetActive(IsExistingClusterChosen)
                .SetDefine(DefineExistingAccountName))
            .Message("Thank you, processing your request.")
            .Build();
    }

 private static Task<bool> DefineExistingAccountName(BoardForm state, Field<BoardForm> field)
    {
        foreach (var account in GetExistingAccountNames(state.ExistingClusterName))
            field
                .AddDescription(account, account)
                .AddTerms(account, account);

        var newAccountChoice = "I want a new account";
        field
            .AddDescription(c_newAccountRequest, newAccountChoice)
            .AddTerms(c_newAccountRequest, newAccountChoice);

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

public class BoardForm
    {
    [Prompt("Please choose from the following existing account names or ask for a new account name. Your new cluster will be created in this account {||}")]
        public string ExistingAccountName;
    }
```

Here's an example for how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Ravit, can you please post the code of your Form too? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I added a simplified version of it to the question.

Comment: mmm I simplified your code so I can compile it... and it looks just fine.. (see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKdQy.png).. what version of bot builder are u using?